# strange crash on testFlight on startup

Tags: swift, react-native, testflight

I have a real strange crash when I launch my app on TestFlight. this the crash log from test flight.

```
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread: 0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0 CoreFoundation 0x183f619d4 __exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:199)
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x197912b54 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2 React 0x1032d3e50 RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:145)
3 React 0x1032ea3a8 __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke + 716 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:981)
4 libdispatch.dylib 0x183b99298 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1454)
5 libdispatch.dylib 0x183b9a280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:559)
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x183b7c5b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 856 (inline_internal.h:2548)
7 CoreFoundation 0x183ee15d0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
8 CoreFoundation 0x183edba78 __CFRunLoopRun + 2480 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
9 CoreFoundation 0x183edab90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
10 GraphicsServices 0x19a1fd598 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2259)
11 UIKitCore 0x1867c4638 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052 (UIApplication.m:3266)
12 UIKitCore 0x1867c9bb8 UIApplicationMain + 164 (UIApplication.m:4738)
13 AppOfCards 0x100be8014 main + 68 (APIManager.swift:22)
14 libdyld.dylib 0x183bb9588 start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001af0a184c __pthread_kill + 8
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001ca5fd9e8 pthread_kill + 212 (pthread.c:1388)
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x000000018cc0d970 __abort + 112 (abort.c:147)
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x000000018cc0d900 abort + 112 (abort.c:118)
4 libc++abi.dylib 0x0000000197a0ecc8 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:76)
5 libc++abi.dylib 0x0000000197a00ca0 demangling_terminate_handler() + 296 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
6 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000197912e04 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
7 FirebaseCrashlytics 0x000000010287e484 0x10284c000 + 205956
8 FirebaseCrashlytics 0x000000010285c504 FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 276 (FIRCLSException.mm:333)
9 libc++abi.dylib 0x0000000197a0e154 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
10 libc++abi.dylib 0x0000000197a0e0ec std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000183b9a294 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:562)
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000183b7c5b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 856 (inline_internal.h:2548)
13 CoreFoundation 0x0000000183ee15d0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
14 CoreFoundation 0x0000000183edba78 __CFRunLoopRun + 2480 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
15 CoreFoundation 0x0000000183edab90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
16 GraphicsServices 0x000000019a1fd598 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2259)
17 UIKitCore 0x00000001867c4638 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052 (UIApplication.m:3266)
18 UIKitCore 0x00000001867c9bb8 UIApplicationMain + 164 (UIApplication.m:4738)
19 AppOfCards 0x0000000100be8014 main + 68 (APIManager.swift:22)
20 libdyld.dylib 0x0000000183bb9588 start + 4
```

I didn't understand the log and the reason for the problem. When I check the report, I think about firebase exception but I'm not sure.

Any help please

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Just encountered the same issue as of today, not using Firebase at all tho. If I find anything I'll post a reply back ;)

Comment: What is/was your React Native version + iOS Target Deploy version?